# Is there anyway to share stateful variables in dataflow pipeline?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm making dataflow pipeline with python.
I want to share global variables across pipeline transform and across worker nodes like global variables (across multiple workers).

Is there any way to support this?
thanx in advance

Comment: Why do you need to do this? It's an immediate alarm bell if you need to share state. Dataflow is a distributed architecture. There is no built in mechanism for sharing data/state across workers. You can use side inputs if your data is static.

Comment: Next to static look-up using side-input there is per window, per key state.

Full explanation (including code examples) can be found [in this blogpost](https://beam.apache.org/blog/2017/02/13/stateful-processing.html).

Comment: What about persist value to shared KV store like redis?

Comment: Can we request this feature to Apache Beam Comittee?

Comment: @TerryCho you can propose new feature ideas by opening a [JIRA issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM/component/12328907). You may want to first start a discussion about your use-case on the [BEAM mailing list](https://github.com/apache/beam#contact-us).

Comment: As stated by Graham there is no shared state among workers. Can you explain more about scenario why you need shared state among different workers?

Comment: You should be able to use a cache like memcached, redis or others. Just let the ParDos access it directly. Does this make sense? You should be aware that this can limit the scalability of your pipeline; and will likely become a bottleneck once you go above a number of workers.

Answer (score 2):

Stateful processing may be of use for sharing state between workers of a specific node (would not be able to share between transforms though):
https://beam.apache.org/blog/2017/02/13/stateful-processing.html