# Apache Beam - how to save a variable from a DoFn for use later in pipeline?

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I've built a Beam/Dataflow pipeline to process shapefiles. I have this simple pipeline:

```py
    with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as p:
        feature_collection = (p
         | beam.Create([known_args.gcs_url])
         | 'LoadShapefile' >> beam.ParDo(LoadShapefile()))
         | beam.Map(print)
```

```py
class LoadShapefile(beam.DoFn):
    def process(self, gcs_url):
        with beam.io.gcp.gcsio.GcsIO().open(gcs_url, 'rb') as f:
            collection = BytesCollection(f.read())
            return iter(collection)
```

This pipeline works great, but I need to capture an additional attribute of `collection` that isn't available to each element inside it. I need `collection.crs` to be available as a variable or argument inside a `DoFn` or `beam.Map` later in the pipeline in order to correctly process each element.

I'd like to return something like this:

```
return (collection.crs, iter(collection))
```

but I cannot figure out how to separate out the collection iterator and the `.crs` property and have the pipeline work properly. Basically in the non-Beam world, I might consider setting a global variable `crs` that is available everywhere, but that isn't possible in Beam AFAIK.

What is the correct way to accomplish this in Beam?

EDIT: `collection.crs` is a small `dict` that will look something like this: `{'init': 'epsg:2284'}`. This dict will never contain more than a couple items, but this metadata is vital for correct processing of the elements in `collection`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a tagged output for you little dictionary and then use that as a side input for your next step, but you would have to implement a branching logic.

Can you not use the information right then and there to refine the data before you pass it along the pipeline?

Comment: I could use it there, but I believe that would diminish the parallelizability of the pipeline. I tried setting up a tagged output but could never get it working. If that's the right approach, I will try again to get that working.

Comment: I don't know if it's the right, it's what I would try :)  Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44432556/is-there-anyway-to-share-stateful-variables-in-dataflow-pipeline) and the links therein help?

Answer (score 0):

You could output an iterable of tuples with the collection's dictionary, like so:

```
class LoadShapefile(beam.DoFn):
    def process(self, gcs_url):
        with beam.io.gcp.gcsio.GcsIO().open(gcs_url, 'rb') as f:
            collection = BytesCollection(f.read())
            return [(elm, collection.crs) for elm in collection]
```

You could also set is as a side input:

```
class LoadShapefile(beam.DoFn):
    def process(self, gcs_url):
        with beam.io.gcp.gcsio.GcsIO().open(gcs_url, 'rb') as f:
            collection = BytesCollection(f.read())
            for elm in collection:
                yield elm
            yield TaggedOutput('crsdata', collection.crs)
```

And then you would do something like this:

```
    with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as p:
        feature_collections = (p
         | beam.Create([known_args.gcs_url])
         | 'LoadShapefile' >> beam.ParDo(LoadShapefile()))
        collection_crs = beam.pvalue.AsSingleton(feature_collections['crsdata'])
        feature_collection = feature_collections['main']
        # Use these PCollections as you see fit.
```

Note that this only works for a single gcs_url input. If you have more, then your side input should be a `Map` or a `List` instead of a `Singleton`.